# Fix Memory Leak VBA DOM HtmlDocument

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, dom, memory-leaks

I'm reading some thousands webpages via automation and importing parts of them into an MS Access database.

For that I have used 3 main strategies:

1. Automating a **webbrowser**
2. Getting the content of the pages via **Ajax** and load them into an
   htmldocument
3. Using the **createdocumentfromurl** method

All the aforementioned produce memory leaking.

This worries me because the app can crash or even freeze the user pc.

By using the **Sleep** API function after setting to **Nothing** the **HtmlDocument** I can recover most of the leaked memory but not all... and waiting delays my procedure anyway.

I would like to ask if anyone can point me to an API function that allows me to **flush** unnecessary objects from memory, or to someway for forcing the **garbage collector** to completely remove those objects after they are set to nothing, or to any other method or technique that allow me to recover/avoid memory leaking.

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem I solved by removing any scripts in the page before loading the content into an html object. No leaking observed after that.

HTH